# Do TCP and UDP each have separate set of ports?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I know that both TCP and UDP can have same port. But I also read that it was for high level protocols. I want to know if they also have a separate set of ports for their exclusive usage? Do they  each have 65535 ports assigned to them? I am confused and  a little clarification could greatly help.

Comment: No, TCP and UDP don't share ports. Each port is exclusively either TCP or UDP. Any good book or tutorial should have explained it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude TCP and UDP can use the same port at the same time, since the OS can easily distinguish traffic for either one, and some commercial network protocols I have worked with before actually depend on making a TCP connection and then receiving UDP on the same port. In fact, Microsoft's own RDP protocol for Remote Desktop does this, as do DNS servers that support queries over both TCP and UDP

Comment: @RemyLebeau Maybe I expressed myself a little badly. What I mean is that you can bind a TCP socket to port X, then you can bind an UDP socket another port X which have the same number. The ports are still not the "same", only its numeric value is the same. To expand: An endpoint is uniquely identified by three things: Address, port number and protocol family (TCP or UDP) (I think there was a fourth thing but I forgot it).  It's not possible for two endpoints to be exactly equal, one of the three (four?) have to be different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "*you can bind a TCP socket to port X, then you can bind an UDP socket another port X which have the same number*" - yes. "*An endpoint is uniquely identified by three things: Address, port number and protocol family (TCP or UDP)*" - yes. "*It's not possible for two endpoints to be exactly equal*" - actually it is possible, albeit rare. For example, two TCP clients on the same machine can be bound to the same local endpoint, as long as they are connected to different remote endpoints. And two UDP sockets on the same machine can be bound to the same local endpoint, too.

Comment: Even for UDP itself, you can listen port 8888 on interface A, while at the same time listen port 8888 on interface B. Thus I think it is each "Interface-Protocol" combination that has separate set of "port numeric values"

Answer (score 1):

I think you should get some book or tutorial on this matter.

Like  @Some programmer dude said "Each port is exclusively either TCP or UDP".For eg : for HTTP default TCP port is 80, Telnet is 23, for DHCP UDP port 67/68 and so on... Having a look at this Wikipedia page might clear your doubt :
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Comment: To clarify:  TCP port x can be in use by one program, while simultaneously UDP port x can be in use for a completely different purpose.  For example, you could have a web server accepting incoming TCP connections on TCP-port-80, while simultaneously having some other unrelated program receiving UDP packets on UDP-port-80, and they wouldn't interfere with each other.